# Retrieve column based on on secondary column all having same value

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that holds schedule entry items.  It has an ID which is the ID of a related schedule record and a VALUE which is a Y or N to indicate whether it is complete.

I need a query to return the `ID` when all `VALUE` equals Y.  So in the example table below, I would want the query to return an IDs of 2 and 3.

I've tried variations of multiple queries using `COUNT(*)`, embedded select statements, etc. but I'm not having any luck.

Would really appreciate any help!

```
+------+------+
|ID    |VALUE |
+------+------+
|1     |Y     |
+------+------+
|1     |Y     |
+------+------+
|1     |N     |
+------+------+
|2     |Y     |
+------+------+
|2     |Y     |
+------+------+
|3     |Y     |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to compare the number of rows for an `ID` value with the number of `Y` values for that `ID` (making use of the fact that MySQL treats a true value as 1 and false as 0):

```
SELECT ID
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(VALUE = 'Y')
```

Output

```
ID
2
3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mk33RmSCykDnNH4wCLSk7J/0)

Comment: That's awesome - REALLY appreciate it!